Nginx custom locations for multiple app access (different ports) on Synology
I am really new in this topic.
What i want to achieve: I have different tools that i use on my synology.
Instead of connecting to all of the different tools with subdomains I want to use one domain with subfolders, like this:

Mainpage: domain.xy - running on 54001
App1: domain.xy/app1 - running on 810
App2: domain.xy/app2 - running on 8044 etc.
Is this even possible? From what I found: yes. But somehow it isnt working.

FYI: I forwarded 443 and 80 to Nginx, nothing else. Is this correct?
This i my config file:
# ------------------------------------------------------------
# domain.duckdns.org
# ------------------------------------------------------------


map $scheme $hsts_header {
    https   "max-age=63072000; preload";
}

server {
  set $forward_scheme https;
  set $server         "192.168.178.40";
  set $port           54001;

  listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

listen 443 ssl;
listen [::]:443 ssl;

  server_name domain.duckdns.org;

  # Let's Encrypt SSL
  include conf.d/include/letsencrypt-acme-challenge.conf;
  include conf.d/include/ssl-ciphers.conf;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/npm-6/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/npm-6/privkey.pem;

    # Force SSL
    include conf.d/include/force-ssl.conf;


proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
proxy_http_version 1.1;

  access_log /data/logs/proxy-host-1_access.log proxy;
  error_log /data/logs/proxy-host-1_error.log warn;

  location /npm {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP      $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass       http://nginx-proxy-manager-app-1:81;

    # Force SSL
    include conf.d/include/force-ssl.conf;

    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;

  }

  location /test {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP      $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass       http://localhost:8044;

    # Force SSL
    include conf.d/include/force-ssl.conf;

    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;

  }

  location / {

    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    
    # Proxy!
    include conf.d/include/proxy.conf;
  }

  # Custom
  include /data/nginx/custom/server_proxy[.]conf;
}

I tried different formatting, like location /npm/ { etc. but its not working. I always get 502 Bad Gateway openresty
